# Bicycles: What determines braking power?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, everyday-life

Today I had an argument with a guy over what the main source of braking power in a bike comes from. (We define "braking power" informally as the ability of a bike to stop quickly.)

He said that the main things that matter for braking power are the brake pads (i.e. the clamps that squeeze a wheel to make it stop moving) and the metal treads on the inner rim of the bike that are squeezed by the brake pads. He claimed that the rubber on the tire shouldn't matter much since stopping the bike "is not what [the rubber is] made for." I think his argument was that the faster the wheel itself could come to a sudden stop, the faster the entire bike would stop, almost regardless of tire material.

I said that the quality (namely, "stickiness") of rubber on the tire should matter, since that is what should determine the coefficients of static and kinetic friction.

So, given an average bike, which is more important for determining its braking power --- Tire rubber, or the quality of the brake pads?

(In particular, if we had a bike with amazing brake pads that stopped the wheels almost instantaneously, but whose tire rubber was worn-out and slippery, would it still be able to stop effectively, with minimal skidding? How would this compare with a bike with poor brake pads but with high-friction rubber? How does "pumping the brakes" (like in ABS) change things?)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would guess that it might be because it's not a terribly interesting question and not particularly about physics (but the application of some physics principles for use in an engineering-like situation).

Comment: Ah, that's fair. I guess this question would have been better suited for Bicycle StackExchange.

Answer (score 3):

When the braking system is functioning within design limits the friction between pads and wheel determines braking power. If friction between the tyre and the road is exceeded, then the braking system is operating outside design limits. There is a loss of control when sliding as nothing now distinguishes transverse and lateral motion - one cannot steer.

In the scenario of strong braking but poor road to tyre friction, the road to tyre friction sets a maximum limit on decelerration. This would be achieved by an uncontrolled slide (no steering).

ABS keeps the braking system inside design limits by reducing braking if the wheel starts to slide.